# Same part of a subquery in multiple select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
TABLEMAIN

Q1  Name  Group  Zone  Month  Type
1   'N1'  'G1'   'Z1'  12     'T1'
4   'N1'  'G3'   'Z2'  12     'T6'
6   'N1'  'G1'   'Z5'  12     'T2'
3   'N2'  'G4'   'Z5'  12     'T4'
.
.
.
```

And I have something like this to get certain results

```
Query1:
select
(SUM(CASE Q1>=2 and Q1<=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TOTAL,
(CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) T1TYPE,
(CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) T2TYPE,
Type,
**Zone,**
Month
from 
TABLEMAIN
GROUP BY Type, **Zone,** Month;

Query2:
select
(SUM(CASE Q1>=2 and Q1<=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TOTAL,
(CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) T1TYPE,
(CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) T2TYPE,
Type,
**Group,**
Month
from 
TABLEMAIN
GROUP BY Type, **Group,** Month;
```

As you can see I group this table many times in many ways, but this part is the same in every query

```
select
(SUM(CASE Q1>=2 and Q1<=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TOTAL,
(CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) T1TYPE,
(CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) T2TYPE,
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm not sure if I can use a materialized view for this

Comment: Put it in a cursor and get the values into a variable and use the variable in each select. So technically you'll be executing it only once.

Comment: Have a look at the [WITH clause](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps.  You can do it all in one query, if you like by using `grouping sets`:

```
select SUM(CASE Q1>=2 and Q1<=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL,
       (CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as T1TYPE,
       (CASE WHEN Type = 'T1' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN Q1=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as T2TYPE
       Type, **Zone,**, **Group,** Month
from TABLEMAIN
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Type, **Zone,** Month), (Type, **Group,** Month));
```

This puts all the results in a single table.

Answer (score 1):

I second with @GolezTrol comment. Would like to explain further.

`SUBQUERY FACTORING` is what you need. The `WITH` clause, or subquery factoring clause, is part of the SQL-99 standard and was added into the Oracle SQL syntax in Oracle 9.2. The WITH clause may be processed as an inline view or resolved as a temporary table. The advantage of the latter is that repeated references to the `subquery` may be more efficient as the data is easily retrieved from the temporary table, rather than being required by each reference.

```
WITH data AS(
<your subquery>
)
SELECT * FROM data
bla bla bla...
```